# Parsing User Input - Batch Scripting

Tags: parsing, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I have been trying to figure this issue out for quite some time now and I am just stuck. I am simply trying to easily parse user input on the command line.

here is what I have so far:

```
set /p "cmd=hk -> "

for %%a in (%cmd%) do (
   echo %%a
)
```

With the above code, if I put in the following command:

```
hk > welcome john
```

It will return the following:

```
welcome
John
```

Now, what I am trying to do is have the output look something like this:

```
Hello John, how are you?
```

I tried using %%b, which would be the name of the person, however it did not work. I am very new to batch scripting, so I am just having some trouble understanding some things like this, for example. If anyone could help me figure this out, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I strongly suggest you to change the topic title (and the description) to something more descriptive, like "How to get second word from a string?". Your current title and description is confusing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following batch file:

```
set /p "cmd=hk -> "
for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%a in ("%cmd%") do (
   echo Hello %%a, how are you?
)
```

Input:

```
Welcome John
```

Output:

```
Hello John, how are you?
```

---

See [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) for the details of how to use `tokens` and `delims`.

Answer (score 0):

```
set /p "cmd=hk -> "

for /f %%a in ("%cmd%") do (
   echo Hello %%a, how are you?
)
```

to parse a strings you need [`FOR /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

Comment: Thank you @npocmaka for your quick response. I tried the above code and I got the following output when I put in the command 'welcome John': Hello welcome, how are you?